Hi Where can I find a sample Google fit data directly after it being exported and some info about data export
I am working on a project and I need participant to export the health data (fit app.) I use an iPhone which only has one health app and exporting it is kinda easy, but I am not sure with Android. I read that not all Android devices use the default Fit app, is that right? Is there an app on all Android devices for all the fit data (steps count, walking distance, and so on.) ? If not, are all other app connected to Google takeout by default? or do they have to to the process of syncing the?
Also, I am searching for ways to get a sample of Google fit data so I can run my software on, where can I find one that is published online? Thank you
I honestly couldn't try much as I dont have an Android device nor I know anyone that has one.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
